# Nested triggering of events in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, eventtrigger

i use this code for trigger an event:

```
$input = array(1,2,3);
$result = $EventManager->trigger('onChangeArray',$this,array('values'=>$input));
$c = $result->count();
$final = array();
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    $final = array_merge($final , $result->pop());
```

i want change this array in attach function. if i add to array, $final contain all values Properly; but i want to remove a value from $final in attach function. i need to call attach functions for nesting that each time the function call with returned array from previous function.
i use this code for add value to array in BootStrap:

```
$SharedManager->attach('Identifier', 'onChangeArray', function($e) {
     $values = $e->getParam('values');
     $values[] = 4 ;
     return $values;
});
```

if possible please help me for remove from array.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following the question. Do you just want to know how to remove a value from an array of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it now. Instead of getting the returned values from the result collection as you're doing with your `for` loop, create an event object containing the values, and have your listeners act on that array instead.

```
$input = array(1,2,3);
$event = new \Zend\EventManager\Event('onChangeArray', $this, array('values' => $input));
$EventManager->trigger($event);

$values = $event->getParam('values');
```

Because the event is passed by reference, your listeners don't need to return anything, they just need to act on the `values` parameter. Consider the following two listeners, one adding and one removing from the array. Neither return a value directly, they both act on the `values` param contained in the `$event` they were given

```
$SharedManager->attach('Identifier', 'onChangeArray', function($e) {
    $values = $e->getParam('values');
    // add value 4 to array
    $values[] = 4 ;
    $e->setParam('values', $values);
});

$SharedManager->attach('Identifier', 'onChangeArray', function($e) {
    $values = $e->getParam('values');
    // remove value of 3 from array
    if (($key = array_search(3, $values)) !== false) {
        unset($values[$key]);
    }
    $e->setParam('values', $values);
});
```

After triggering the event as directed in the first step, you'll find that the `values` param in your event contains the final array...

```
// ..
$EventManager->trigger($event);
$values = $event->getParam('values');

\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($values);
// result
array(3) {
    [0] => int(1)
    [1] => int(2)
    [3] => int(4)
}
```